# Base class for custom components

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, mxml

In my flex app I have various custom components done with mxml or actionscript.
I want all of them to extend a base-class where I can define properties/event listeners etc.
Can someone give me an example how to create that base class and how I can extend it in mxml and actionscript components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Creating the base class:**

*ActionScript*

In BaseClass.as:

```
public class BaseClass
{
}
```

**Extending from the base class:**

*ActionScript*

```
public class SubClass extends BaseClass
{
}
```

*MXML*

In a file called SubClass.mxml:

```
<ns:BaseClass xmlns:ns="path.to.base.*">
</ns:BaseClass>
```

Comment: But some of actionScript based components already built-in flex components. like this:
public class MyButton extends Button
{
}
How do I make those extend the new BaseClass?

Comment: That would require multiple inheritance, which ActionScript doesn't officially support.  There is a way to get something that's pretty close using #include, but it's kind of messy.  See http://www.darronschall.com/weblog/2006/10/multiple-inheritance-in-actionscript-3.cfm for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could write a common interface for your components, just with the methods they need to implement

```
public interface ICustomComponent {

    function doSomething():void; 

    // more methods here

}
```

And then in your AS components you just implement the ICustomComponent interface (or however you named it)

```
public class CustomButton extends Button implements ICustomComponent {

    public function doSomething():void {

    }
}
```

You can do this in MXML components too :

```
<mx:Button xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
    implements="ICustomComponent">

    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            public function doSomething():void {
                // blah blah
            }               

        ]]>      
    </mx:Script>

</mx:Button>
```

Just an idea. Hope it helps
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

In the example below the component extends Form to create an address form .

Instead of form you can extend your own component .

When using actionscript i would suggest investigating flex components lifecycle for best performance : 
http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=ascomponents_advanced_2.html

mx:Form xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" xmlns:MyComp="*"

```
<mx:FormItem label="NameField">
    <mx:TextInput/>
</mx:FormItem>

<mx:FormItem label="Street">
    <mx:TextInput/>
</mx:FormItem>

<mx:FormItem label="City" > 
    <mx:TextInput/>
</mx:FormItem>

<mx:FormItem label="State" > 
    <MyComp:StateComboBox/>
</mx:FormItem>
```

The following application file references the AddressForm component in the

AddressForm tag:

mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
    xmlns:MyComp="*"

```
<MyComp:AddressForm/>
```

/mx:Application

from http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=mxmlcomponents_1.html

Comment: But some of actionScript based components already built-in flex components. like this:
public class MyButton extends Button
{
}
How do I make those extend the new BaseClass?

Comment: If you are looking for multiple inharitance like in java , actionscript does not support it . you can use mutiple inerfaces which might help you 
MyButton extends Button { } implements ICustomButtons , IEventDispacher